# Enable Firefox Click-To-Play for SPECIFIC Plugins?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, plugins

Basically, what I want to do is to enable Firefox Click-To-Play for specific plugins (like Java since its not that secure) while allowing it for plugins like Flash. While there are many instructions on enabling/disabling CTP for specific sites, there is nothing listed for specific plugins.

Is what I am saying even possible? Is there a hack or something that does what I want?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you should uninstall the Java Webstart plugin.

Secondly, it's not click-to-play but [QuickJava](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quickjava/) extension lets you toggle plugins quite easily.

There is [another extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/click-to-play-switch) that is [click-to-play](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Issues_related_to_plugins#Click_to_Play) that lets you choose which plugins to control but it's buggy.

Answer (score 0):

[How to get click to play working in Firefox 23 or newer](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/08/07/how-to-get-click-to-play-working-in-firefox-23-or-newer/) explains it very nicely.

First:

- Type `about:config` in Firefox's address bar and confirm that you will be careful when the message comes up (on first visit only).
- Search for `plugins.click_to_play` and set it to **true** by double-clicking its preference name.

Then, open your plugins page (Tools > Add-ons > Plugins). In there, make appropriate choices for each plugin.

The choices are:

- `Never Activate` means it is disabled and won't be activated unless you modify the state in the plugins manager.
- `Always Activate` means that the plugin will always be loaded automatically.
- `Ask to Activate` means that `Click to Play` will be used.

But do read the linked article for full details.